# There exists a prime between $n+1$ and $n^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've been checking my university's past exams and I've found the following problem:

> Let $p_n$ be the $n-$th prime. Prove that: $p_n\le2^{2^{n-1}}$.

The main idea I'm trying to prove is that $p_n^2\ge p_{n+1}$, I know that Bertrand's postulate give the much better bound $2p_n\ge p_{n+1}$ but I'm trying to stay in the course's context.

Of course this translates to the existence of a prime in $\{p_n+1, \cdots, p_n^2\}$. We'll show that for each positive integer $n$ there exists a prime in $\{n+1, \cdots, n^2\}$.

Mimicking Erdös's proof of Bertrand's postulate; We consider the binomial coefficient $\binom{n^2}{n}$, each prime that divides it satisfies: $\displaystyle p^{v_p\binom{n^2}{n}}\le n^2$, by Legender's formula. Supposing that no prime is in: $\{n+1, \cdots, n^2\}$, and using the fact that there are at most $\displaystyle \frac{n+1}2$ primes in $\{1, \cdots, n\}$, we get: $\binom{n^2}{n}\le (n^2)^{\frac{n+1}2}=n^{n+1}$, which fails for $n\ge 3$.

My question is: is there an easier method to prove that $p_n^2\ge p_{n+1}$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There is a prime between $n$ and $n^2$, without Bertrand](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594162/there-is-a-prime-between-n-and-n2-without-bertrand) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24p_n%5E2%5Cge%20p_%7Bn%2B1%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprime&p=1). Note there are also some fairly similar questions, e.g., [What's the history of the result that $p_{n+1} < p_n^2$, and how difficult is the proof?](/q/57335), ...

Comment: (cont.) [Elementary proofs of prime gap theorems?](/q/1113166), [Is the next prime number always the next number divisible by the current prime number, except for any numbers previously divisible by primes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3162271/602049), etc. After looking briefly through the answers to these questions, I noticed that several are basically the same or very similar to your proof, but with there apparently not being any that I would consider to be easier than what you did.

Comment: Note that the quoted problem is also a dupe, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/65630/242).